# Batch: Xcopy current date

Tags: date, batch-file

So https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771254.aspx describes the `/d` parameter of the `xcopy` command as allowing you to only copy the source file changed on or after the specified date, so I wanted to use the underneath command but with the current date. Does anyone know how to get the current date in batch and properly format it within the below command?

```
xcopy /d [:MM-DD-YYYY]
```

Comment: Might be helpful : How to get current datetime on Windows command line, in a suitable format for using in a filename?  http://stackoverflow.com/q/203090/4291215

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@echo off
for /F "usebackq tokens=1,2 delims==" %%i in (`wmic os get LocalDateTime /VALUE 2^>NUL`) do if '.%%i.'=='.LocalDateTime.' set ldt=%%j
set yyyy=%ldt:~0,4%
set mm=%ldt:~4,2%
set dd=%ldt:~6,2%

echo xcopy source destination /D:%mm%-%dd%-%yyyy% /L
```

remove `echo` in front of `xcopy`, edit `source` and `destination`. `/L` is to list only, no destructive command.

Comment: This code gives me an invalid `/d` parameter. When I echo `%mm%-%dd%-%yyyy%`, I get `~4,2-~6,2-~0,4`, not today's date.

Comment: It works when I use only your above 5 lines. When I insert it into my batch, it isn't working. I'll see why